# Why does my .Range function return a 1004 runtime error

Tags: vba, range, excel-2013

I'm writing a code as basically a proof of concept so that I can accurately use in my code after I finish seeing how it operates. However, though try as I might, despite all my online searches, I can't seem to identify why my code returns a 1004 error nor do I know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J3:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=J2+G2"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K3:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=K2+H2"

Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & c).Value <> ""
    c = c + 1
Loop

MsgBox c
```

The problem seems to be at the call of the Range function itself, as everything works fine when I remove said problem.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't qualify the context of `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. It has to be "somewhere", i.e. in the context of a workbook, for example `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.
- You never initiate the variable `c`. Bad practice.
- You also never initialize the variable `LastRow`. Again, bad practice.

When the macro starts, what value do you THINK these two variables should have? How should Excel **know** what you THINK if you don't tell it?

Dim the variable and assign it an initial value.

Always `Dim` your variables. Also, in order to avoid stuff-ups like this, use `Option Explicit` as the first line in any module. That will sanity-check code and point out errors before it compiles. It will enforce the good habit to declare all variables before they are being used and will pick up a lot of other stuff

[image]

Compare to

```
Option Explicit

Sub stuff()
Dim c As Long, LastRow As Long
c = 1
LastRow = 20 ' or use code to work out the last row

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J3:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=J2+G2"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K3:K" & LastRow).Formula = "=K2+H2"

Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & c).Value <> ""
    c = c + 1
Loop

MsgBox c
End Sub
```

Comment: My c variable is a global variable, I have it working a similar purpose in another class. However I see that I had included LastRow not knowing that it wasn't a function of VBA. Also, as I understand it, "J3:J" refers to entire column of J with no restrictions on length right? Anyways, adding "ThisWorkbook." and removing "LastRow" still gives me the error. Thanks again for the time you're giving to this

Comment: I found my problem, VBA doesn't work with unlimited length, I needed to included a limit. Thanks for the help, i got it working.